# Jquery image rollover - slide transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, transition

How can I use Jquery to change image on hover with slide up transition? I've searched on the internet but I can't found a working code. All codes that I've found use fadeIn or fadeOut. Thank you very much!

This is the code that I found, but it uses fade in and out:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('.change').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).slideUp('fast', function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('on'));
    $(this).fadeIn();
  });
});

$('.change').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).slideUp('fast', function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('off'));
    $(this).fadeIn();
  });
});
});</script>
```

AND html:

```
<img class="change" src="images/portofoliu/next.gif" data-on="images/portofoliu/prev.gif" data-off="images/portofoliu/next.gif">
```

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Comment: You can use CSS3 for all that animation

Comment: Yes, I know that CSS 3 is a good option, but IE doesn't like CSS3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123" />

$('#clickme').hover(function() {
  $('#book').slideUp('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GFdW5/3/

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

**EDIT:** Final Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/hellomynameisluc/frTFw

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, this code seems not working at me... I do something wrong?

Comment: Is your jquery version up to date?

Comment: Ok, I've found the error! There was a copy error :) . It work's now, thank you, but it only slide up image, and i want to change the image by sliding up. Sorry for my English...

Comment: Oh I see. That's a bit more involved. Give me a minute to find something.

Comment: No, I want to make a hover change image like http://www.uelike.com/ (the right slideshow - the next / prew arrows)...

Comment: There are gray arrows which turns in green arrows with slide up.

Comment: No problemo. Happy Coding! :)